# How to modify Shopify's web-pixels-manager-setup script?

Tags: shopify

it seems that Shopify's web-pixels-manager-setup script broadcasts some data from the shop, including vendor.

I do not want vendor to be shown in the source code. Anyone faced similar problem and could help me please? Thanks.

I disabled in theme, settings etc vendor from being shown, but it's still being broadcasted by web-pixels-manager-setup.

And I can't find a way how to modify it.

Comment: I am wondering the same, our client wants to hide prices for non-logged in users but they are shown in web-pixels-manager-setup. How can I remove this?